# Changing a column value in a database once looped via a php script?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a Database that loops inside a `td` tag column, and i have a database table named as Status. Once `status == "1"` then the selected row of the column should change into "**Active**", if `status == 2` then it should be another output. How do i do something like this while manipulating a database and loop it? Sorry for asking something like this I'm very new to programming

Comment: Run your queries prior to looping trough array of given data.
EX: `select status from x where something`, and loop trough given array.
`if (statement == true) {
     <td> with true data </td> // or status 1
}else {
    <td> with false data </td> // or status 2
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it. I added a simple php script that changes the value inside a data table.

```
if($loopvariable['table_name'] == '1'){
echo "Active"
}elseif{
Etc..
}
```